# row level Trigger code

Tags: plsqldeveloper

HI

I have a table A and Table B
I need to write trigger on table A for each row insert on table A same row should get inserted in Table B
Table A and Table B have same structure.

Please help me with code

Thanks
Xyz,

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/srvrside.htm#i13313

You have to write something like:

```
create or replace trigger replicate
after insert on A
for each row
.
.
.
```